# How to fix the syntax error in AzurePowerShell pipeline task?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I am trying to deploy a self-signed certificate by using the following pipeline task:

```
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
      ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
      azurePowerShellVersion: '2.6.0'
      Inline: |
      $Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String '1234' -Force -AsPlainText
      $Base64 = 'MI..............3000.characters.here............M+wICB9A='
      Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}''-my-keyvault' -Name ccg-self-signed-cert -CertificateString $Base64 -Password $Pwd
```

The 3 Powershell commands listed above work well for me at the PowerShell command prompt.

But when I try run the above pipeline, I get the syntax error:

> /pipelines/shared.yml: (Line: 164, Col: 11, Idx: 7111) - (Line: 164,
>   Col: 11, Idx: 7111): While scanning a simple key, could not find
>   expected ':'.

[image: screenshot error]

What is happening here please?

Is the line 164 with the code `$Base64 = '.....'` too long for a pipeline script?

Or do I have some other issue?

**UPDATE:**

After indenting the inline script (thanks, Mathias!), I get another error, surprisingly talking about a "hostname":

```
##[section]Starting: AzurePowerShell
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
Version      : 5.168.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azurepowershelltroubleshooting
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\13d4bf76-87b6-4ac4-9bb5-51ef481420d0.ps1'"
##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_2.6.0\Az.Accounts\1.7.5\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX -TenantId ***
##[error]Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: AzurePowerShell
```

Is `-VaultName '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}''-my-keyvault'` a correct way to prepend RG name (passed as param) to the string "-my-keyvault"?

**UPDATE 2:**

Using `-VaultName '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}-my-keyvault'` has fixed my problem

Comment: You may need to indent the inline script

Comment: Ah! That is why the error was mentioning a "key"!

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking the parser probably treats the `InlineScript` as an empty (or single-line) list and is looking for a valid YAML key on the following lines

Comment: For some reason now I get the runtime error: `##[error]Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.` eventhough there is no explicit hostname or URI in my task. Or is it the Keyvault URI?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please convert it to an answer ? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise on selecting enable system diagnostic and run pipeline one more to get more detailed info